# TextBox textchange event inside usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, textchanged

I want to trigger textchange event of txtPlanCode inside the usercontrol but unfortunately my textchange is not triggered. whats wrong with my code?

Please help thanks :)

```
 //CodeBehind of my page
protected void ucPlan_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TxtPlanDesc.Text = Session["PlanDesc"].ToString();
}

//Client side (.aspx) 

<uc2:PlanID ID="ucPlanCode" runat="server"  ucPlan_OnTextChanged="ucPlan_OnTextChanged" autopostback="true"/>

//ucPlanID.ascx.cs

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public string PlanID
{
    get
    {
         return txtPlanCode.Text;
    }
    set
    {
         txtPlanCode.Text = value;
    }
 }

 public bool AutoPostBack
 {
     get
     {
          return txtPlanCode.AutoPostBack;
     }
     set
     {
          txtPlanCode.AutoPostBack = value;
     }
 }

 //ucPlanID.ascx 

<asp:TextBox ID="txtPlanCode" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="20" Enabled="true" Text='<%#Eval("PlanCode") %>' OnTextChanged="txtPlanCode_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Add `AutoPostBack="true"` to your control

Answer (score 4):

on user control :

```
  public event EventHandler TextChangeEvent;

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextChangeEvent != null)
            TextChangeEvent(this, e);
    }

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

on page :

```
<script runat="server">
protected void Some_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // your code here 
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: The solution on UserControl section as above bubbles up the event up to the Parent Container that exposes the event to the outside world of the component. It can be simplified by using `TextChangeEvent?.Invoke(this, e)`